# Is it acceptable to maintain an instance of Context in a class not derived from Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I am developing an application where I've passed the Activity's context into a class derived from Object.

Is there anything wrong with doing this?

Comment: AFAIK it is acceptable...Because I did the same in my game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong at all. Every `View` class does that, for instance.

The only danger is maintaining a reference to an `Activity` after it is destroyed. This is a common source of memory leaks. See the blog post [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) for more information about this.

`View` subclasses avoid leaking because references to the views themselves generally go away when the activity is destroyed. If your class instance that is maintaining a reference does not go away like that, then you need to arrange for the reference to go away. One option is to override `onDestroy` for your activity and do some clean-up there. Another is to use a `SoftReference` instead of a hard reference to the context.

Comment: I am actually passing in the context of the main activity. Would there be  case for the main activity getting destroyed before the app is done running?  Even still, I think I'll take Raghav's advice and pass in the Application context since that makes more sense from a semantic standpoint.

Comment: @BrianV - If the device is reoriented, the default behavior of the system is to destroy all your activities and re-create them. Since this does not stop the process, any objects referenced by static fields will maintain all their internal references. Using the application context like Raghav suggests avoid the problem. It will work fine for accessing resources, etc. However, if you need a reference to the activity itself (for example, to call your own custom methods) then you need to look for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Maintaining an instance of a Context like that of an Activity or Service is going to open up ways for memory leaks.

However, keeping a reference to the instance returned by `getApplicationContext()` should be harmless.